# How to get HTML after onchange by Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I`ve trouble on have a HTML document after onchange function by Nokogiri.
Of course, Mechanize lib can control that. but, sadly webpage which I want to control is jsp not HTML.

Generated HTML showes as belows :

form method = "post" name = "mysearchform"

```
<select id = "hall_no" name = "hall_no" onchange = "document.mysearchform.submit()">
      <option value="1" selected=""> 1 </option>
      <option value="2"> 2 </option>
</select>
```

/form

I guess I POST some data by some command, but I`m newbie to Ruby and I can`t find any solution about that.

Is there anybody who`ve know about that?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Nokogiri is a HTML parser and can not execute javascript. Go for something like Capybara with a driver that supports javascript.

See http://github.com/jnicklas/capybara